# Change TinyInt value to 1 PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have been searching and trying different ways for a while with no success.

What I need to do is to change the value in the DB `TINYINT` column from 0 to 1 so as to check if an account has been verified.

Here is the snippet of code. The verify part works OK.

```
$query = "SELECT verify_code
          FROM Member
          WHERE verify_code = '$verify_code';";


$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) // Verfication code not found
{
    die("No such code");
} else {
    $sql = mysqli_query("UPDATE Verified SET Verified = 1 WHERE verify_code = $verfiy_code'");
    header( "Location:TwitchMain.php");
}
```

Comment: see the docs:: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: is `Verified` the name of both the table and the column?

Comment: Typo: `$verfiy_code` vs. `$verify_code`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only did you miss the quote, you also used `mysqli_query` in a wrong way, It needs a connection resource as the first parameter.

```
mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE Member SET Verified = 1 WHERE verify_code = '$verify_code'");
```

**Function Prototype**

> Procedural style

```
mixed mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )
```

**[Reference](https://www.php.net/mysqli_query)**

Answer (score 0):

The Column type is TINYINT , why you have to quote it ???

```
$query = "SELECT verify_code FROM Member WHERE verify_code = $verify_code ";
```

and then in your update query :

```
$update_query = "UPDATE Verified SET Verified = 1 WHERE verify_code = '$verfiy_code' ";
```

Comment: I think that verify code is not a `TINYINT` is a `VARCHAR`, so need to be quoted in `UPDATE` and `SELECT` statements